# Scrapy error - str object has no attribute css

Tags: python, scrapy

```
Article = response.css(‘.article-main).getall()

Len(article)
```

Till here we are getting result

```
Art =article [0]

Art.css(‘.art2-amp::text’).get()
```

Facing error

```
str object has no attribute css. Note html tags are example in css given
```

How do I fix it? I am scraping website facing this error in Scrapy shell.

Comment: Missing code where you declare `response` variable/object.

Answer (score 0):

`getall()` returns extracted data as strings, if you only want selectors don't call it:

```py
Article = response.css(‘.article-main)
Art =article [0]
Art.css(‘.art2-amp::text’).get()
```